# PJSIP with MPTCP for video streaming

Tags: networking, tcp, pjsip, baresip, mptcp

I am planning to test MPTCP capability with regards to video feed quality between two devices over a network. Consider we have two network paths available between the two devices(for example a mobile network and another wifi network).

If one connection path relaying video feed to the other device for example via mobile network drops out or fails, the other connection path available will take over and thus maintaining the video feed quality.I have read about MPTCP in general.

My question is, am i correct to think of a solution based on a mix of MPTCP and PJSIP. If so, what kind of applications should i look into,to START testing/building/prototyping such a concept? Has anyone worked on PJSIP( or baresip) along with MPTCP.

I know the question is vague, but i need a general concept building response which will help me select the right kind of platform(such as SIP) for creating an application . Any advice?

Comment: TCP really sin't appropriate for real-time traffic like voice or video. Those normally use UDP.

Comment: @Ron That is absolutely correct. the delay in the setup to MPTCP connection including underlying subflows would definitely affect the real time capabilities.
i would like to know if there is something similar like MPTCP for video streaming. I have read little about Multipath RTP...however i want to know, will it be the case where if the mobile network streaming falls out, some other subflow network would continue providing constant feed without compromising the Quality of service??

Comment: it would, that's how Apple's Siri is using multipath TCP